# Connecting ROS with opencv for a drone

Tags: python, opencv3.0, ros, ar.drone

I need to recognize human faces using a drone. I have done that in opencv using xmls like
 1. haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
 2. haarcascade_eye.xml

Can somebody help me to connect ROS with Opencv and detect faces from ARDRONE in simpler steps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find out the stable version of ROS in documentation of ROS (org) , a long before i have worked with ROS, this is a commen issue that ROS is being updated day by day so try proper documentation of ROS.

may this link help you: http://wiki.ros.org/opencv3

but recommendation is that please choose the right version of ROS and right configuration to work with, Good Luck!